# Channel Creation failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ OrdererOrg/Writers ]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have tried the tutorial from Hyperledger Fabric with the version 2.3, where they instantiate 2 peers (Org1 and Org2) and an orderer node (Orderer) and tried to move forward to instantiate each node on a different VM. The final goal is to multiply peer and orderer nodes with a raft consensus, with each node his own VM.
I have defined the following configtx.yaml.

```
---
Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member','OrdererMSP.orderer')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member','OrdererMSP.orderer')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

        OrdererEndpoints:
            - orderer0.example.com:7050

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP
        ID: Org1MSP
        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        Name: Org2MSP
        ID: Org2MSP
        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.peer')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 7051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer0.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/tls/server.crt
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:

    AllOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    
    AllOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

On node Org1, after creating the crypto-material with cryptogen, I have created the genesis block and the application channel with configtxgen.

```
configtxgen -profile AllOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block -channelID mychannel
configtxgen -profile AllOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx -channelID mychannel
```

Next, I have shared this item to all nodes and started associated dockers. Next step is to create the channel, so on Org1 VM, I use the following command:

```
peer channel create -o <IP of the ordering node>:7050  --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer0.example.com -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block --tls –cafile ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I have got the following error on my shell:

> 2020-12-15 16:52:38.764 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized

> Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- config update for existing channel did not pass initial checks: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied

Investigated in the orderer logs gives me the following error:

```
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.780 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 368 [0m 0xc000902e60 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.780 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 369 [0m 0xc000902e60 processing identity 0 - &{Org1MSP 6ead373932c104ed8f9aa3da8431824fbe733b84eeee6d8b70a0f2ddca84a932}
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 36a [0m 0xc000902e60 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected OrdererMSP, got Org1MSP)
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 36b [0m 0xc000902e60 principal evaluation fails
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 36c [0m 0xc000902e60 gate 1608051158780630929 evaluation fails
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 36d [0m Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 36e [0m == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 36f [0m Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ OrdererOrg/Writers ]
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 370 [0m Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 371 [0m == Done Evaluating *policies.ImplicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 372 [0m Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Consortiums/Writers Orderer/Writers ]
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 373 [0m Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Writers
 [36m2020-12-15 16:52:38.782 UTC [policies] EvaluateSignedData -> DEBU 374 [0m == Done Evaluating *policies.ImplicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
```

I assume that the orderer policy expects a channel creation demand from an orderer, but only a peer can make it. Maybe I have made a mistake in writing my policies. Please, could you help me to fix my platform?

EDIT: After yours comments, I complete:
Some of the variable environnement of Org1 are:

```
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051
```

The volume section of the orderer container's docker compose file is :

```
volumes:
  - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
  - ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
  - ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer0.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
  - ../orgconfig/orderer.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/orderer.yaml
  - orderer0.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
```

And the Orderer config values associated to its MSP are:

```
General.LocalMSPDir = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp"
General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
General.TLS.Enabled = true
General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
General.TLS.Certificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
General.TLS.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
```

According orderer's logs, the TLS handshake completed with no errors

Comment: What is the value associated with CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH environmental variable?

Comment: Can you give configuration information of orderer container?

Comment: It is a different problem from the error, but for the raft algorithm, at least three odd numbers are recommended as the CFT method. That is, if the orderer is a single node, Raft is not suitable, and to test Raft operation on a separate network, configure 3 or more odd orderers. [fabric-raft](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/orderer/ordering_service.html#raft)

Comment: Is the orderer's mutual tls setting correct?
`GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED`
`GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS`
`GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE`
`GENERAL_CLUSTER_PRIVATEKEY`
Can you also give config values for these items?

Answer (score 0):

The orderer logs might indicate that the certificate you have provided in the orderer's local MSP directory belongs to org1, rather than orderer org. To make sure, go in the orderer logs, and just before the lines you have provided, there must be some public certificates printed out on the logs. Copy them from the logs and throw them on a [pem certificate decoder online](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html) to check which organization they belong to from the attributes of the certificate. If it is indeed the wrong certificate, make sure to include the right ones from the MSP directories for the orderer org that you have generated with cryptogen.

Comment: After checking the logs, the printed certificate belongs effectively to Org1. If I understand correctly, it should be normal because the node  which asks for the channel creation belongs to Org1.
Moreover, I checked the MSP of Orderer and every certificate is associated with the orderer org.
Maybe I missed something?